# What mask is this?

Tags: runescape

I was perusing some of the Runescape forums and I noticed a player profile with this mask I have never seen before. Can someone tell me what it is? Doing a google image search for it revealed nothing and searching "runescape mask with many eyes" also did not return any good results.

**What mask is this?**

[image: Strange mask]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the [shinigami orokami](https://runescape.wiki/w/Shinigami_orokami_mask) mask.

> The shinigami orokami mask is an orokami mask that can be obtained from a murderous orokami as a rare loot from either free-hand catching it or looting a murderous orokami jar.
>
> [image: shinigami orokami mask]

Comment: Thanks! Thing is creepy as hell lol, Im surprised a google search brought up nothing but, glad someone knew what it was :)

Comment: @KyleRone Of course! It’s very creepy indeed